# Laravel Trait Doesn't Excite

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I've a trait function that updating a report, i've done its route and its namespace also im using it in the controller everything is right but when i submit it doesn't run and the page only refreshs

Trait Function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Permit\Trait;

use App\Models\Log;
use App\Models\Permit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

trait HazardsInfo
{
    public function HazardsInfo(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($request);
        $permit = Permit::findOrFail($id);
        $permit->Update([
            'gaurd_names' => $request->gaurd_names,
        ]);
        Log::create([
            'permit_id' => $permit->id,
            'created_by' =>  Auth::user()->id,
            'status' => 'og-complete'
        ]);
        return Redirect::to("/permit/{$id}/edit")->withSuccess('Hazards Has Been Updated');
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::post('/permit/{permit}/edit', [PermitController::class, 'HazardsInfo'])->name('permit.HazardsInfo');
```

blade form

```
<form action="{{ route('permit.HazardsInfo', $permit->id) }}">
    @if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success w-25 ms-2 text-center">
        {{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
    <input type="text" name="gaurd_names">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-label right ms-auto nexttab nexttab" data-nexttab=""><i
            class="ri-arrow-left-line label-icon align-middle fs-16 ms-2"></i>
        Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: What code do you have in your controller, on what model are you calling this trait?

Comment: use HazardsInfo;

Comment: this code i'm using in the controller,calling it in log/permit models

Comment: You can't call a trait function just because the controller has the same name as the model, inside of the controller you must define a HazardsInfo() method where you will use the Permit passed as $permit->HazardsInfo() or something like that

Comment: okay let me try now.

Comment: what does your controller look like?

Comment: like this use HazardsInfo;